# Docker-compose and dockerfile - spoil with common mistakes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

Let's say I've got an app where I want to test someone if he/she know how to deal with docker. To do so I've prepared working dockerfile with simple docker-compose.yml, as a sample I used Rails app, as follows:

`dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose the applications port to the host machine
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run when the container is started.
CMD bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

So now I want to broke these working setup with some common mistakes - do you know such a common mistakes? Delete ports maybe or change app location in dockerfile, what are common mistakes in such setup?

Comment: In my opinion, you should always (1) follow the [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/), (2) not forget to actually set the `ENTRYPOINT` which it appears you have, (3) always pin the versions of whatever you're installing (preferably passing the versions as `ARG`'s and persisting the version in the containers `ENV`), (4) [lint your `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) and (5) split `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` on multiple lines, set `--no-install-recommends` in the `apt -get install`, (6) `WORKDIR` creates the dir..

Comment: declaring an entrypoint and not using it is already interesting. If you want to make it complicate, you can reproduce the error in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156551/docker-mysql-4-0-27-start-problem-after-creating-dockerfile-entrypoint-sh

Comment: Can take this to over to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and can show you everything I'd change before even thinking about how I'd intentionally mess it up.

Comment: Here is a example of an intentionally broken project that I created for work: https://github.com/yields-io/broken-minimal-keycloak

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR;

If you're trying to test their knowledge of `docker` then your `Dockerfile` is already spoiled with common mistakes. If it's testing their knowledge of whatever is running inside the container created from an image built from your `Dockerfile` then it depends on what the application does and if you're trying to test them on their capabilities of debugging an application in general then the sky is the limit on how many hoops you can make them jump from incorrect binaries for the OS, incorrect file permissions, encoding issues, resource allocation, networking, ...

---

#### Current common mistakes

1. ["Split long or complex RUN statements on multiple lines separated with backslashes ..."](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)
2. Pin the version of the `apt` packages that you're installing (**note**: this is by far the most common mistake I see)
3. Don't install packages recommended by `apt` that you do not need
4. ["When you clean up the apt cache by removing /var/lib/apt/lists it reduces the image size ..."](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)
5. ["the instructions `RUN`, `COPY`, `ADD` create layers"](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) and the `WORKDIR` instruction will create the directory if it doesn't already exist - removing the `RUN mkdir app` removes a layer from the final image
6. Pin the version of `gem` packages
7. Chain commands in the `RUN` instruction to reduce the amount of layers in the final image
8. Set the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction in your `Dockerfile`
9. Use JSON notation for `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` arguments

> **Note**: `debain` based images [perform cleanup after every `apt-get install`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/03e2923e42446dbb830c654d0eec323a0b4ef02a/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L82-L105) but `hadolint` will complain if you don't explicitly remove the `apt` files. You can either ignore the linting error or explicitly cleanup after the install, I prefer the latter.

A [`hadolint`](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint)'d version of your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        nodejs=10.21.0~dfsg-1~deb10u1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4 && \ 
    bundle install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "'0.0.0.0'"]
```

Concerning the `docker-compose` configuration, setting the `command` is redundant:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

... regarding the ports being open it really depends on what your expectations are. If you're expecting the person to advise you that mapping ports is meh and that you should proxy traffic to the service (i.e. through `nginx`) then yes that should be considered an issue.

#### Additional common mistakes

A non-exhaustive list of common mistakes I often come across:

1. `COPY`'ing a `tar` archive into an image then un-compressing the `tar` in 2 instructions

```
COPY files.tar.gz /
RUN tar czvf files.tar.gz
```

Can be replaced with `ADD` (removes a layer from the final image) i.e.: `ADD files.tar.gz /`

2. Changing directories then uncompressing `tar` files

```
RUN cd / && tar xzvf files.tar.gz
```

Can change directories with `tar`'s `-C` option before un-compressing the file i.e. `tar -C / xzvf files.tar.gz`

3. `curl`'ing `tar` files then un-compressing them in 2 `RUN`'s

```
RUN curl -Lo files.tar.gz https://example.com/files.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf files.tar.gz
```

Can `pipe` the `curl` output into `tar` in a single `RUN` instruction i.e.: `curl https://example.com/files.tar.gz | tar xzv`

4. Using `pipe`'s without setting `SHELL` options ^ should be:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN curl https://example.com/files.tar.gz | tar -C / xzv
```

5. `COPY`'ing things from a [multi-staged build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) that shouldn't be copied into the final layer:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim as build
# build everything
FROM scratch as target
COPY --from=build /some/random/file .
```

6. `COPY`'ing secrets into builds (use [`buildkit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64036342/1423507) and your `ssh-agent` for cloning repositories in the build)